# Javascript hide var array by default then alternate with a second array when button clicked

Tags: javascript

I have two variables, each with multiple div IDs. One of those variables needs to be hidden by default. Then when a class is clicked with addeventlistener the variables swap visibility.

```
var click1 = document.getElementsByClassName('buffalo');

var click2 = document.getElementsByClassName('tiger');

var hide1 = ['widget2', 'widget4', 'widget6', 'widget8', 'widget10', 'widget12'];

var hide2 = ['widget1', 'widget3', 'widget5', 'widget7', 'widget9', 'widget11'];
```

In the code above I need var hide2 to be hidden by default. So the only widgets showing are var hide1.

When a user clicks var click1 nothing should happen because the widgets for that button are already showing.

When a user clicks var click2, var hide 2 widgets should become visible and var hide 1 widgets should be hidden.

Then if a user clicks var click1, var hide 1 widgets should become visible and var hide 2 widgets should be hidden.

I have experimented with .toggle however, I need to keep this in strictly javascript.

Here is the code I have been playing with,

```
 click1.addEventListener('click', function() {

       for(i = 0; i < hide1.length; i++)   {
    if (document.getElementById(hide2[i]).style.display == "block") {
    document.getElementById(hide2[i]).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(hide1[i]).style.display = "block";
         } 

       }
    })


    click2.addEventListener('click', function() {

       for(i = 0; i < hide2.length; i++)   {
    if (document.getElementById(hide1[i]).style.display == "block") {
    document.getElementById(hide1[i]).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(hide2[i]).style.display = "block";
          } 

       }
    });
```

Comment: can you add the code you have experimented with ?

Comment: yes! Editing now

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work if you are willing to rearrange your process a little
have your collection of div's by className, then forEach element, toggle the "hide" class. I tested the following:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            .hide {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener("load", function() {
                var click1 = document.getElementsByClassName("buffalo");
                var click2 = document.getElementsByClassName("tiger");
                [].forEach.call(click1, element => {
                    console.log(element.innerHtml);
                    element.classList.toggle("hide");
                });
                var hideb = document.getElementById("hideB");
                hideb.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    [].forEach.call(click1, element => {
                        element.classList.toggle("hide");
                    });
                    [].forEach.call(click2, element => {
                        element.classList.toggle("hide");
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="hideB">toggle</button>

        <div class="buffalo">widget1</div>
        <div class="buffalo">widget3</div>
        <div class="buffalo">widget5</div>
        <div class="buffalo">widget7</div>
        <div class="buffalo">widget9</div>
        <div class="buffalo">widget11</div>

        <div class="tiger">widget2</div>
        <div class="tiger">widget4</div>
        <div class="tiger">widget6</div>
        <div class="tiger">widget8</div>
        <div class="tiger">widget10</div>
        <div class="tiger">widget12</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what about without editing css or HTML? I am unable to modify the classes or the divs

Comment: ah... ok is click1 a collection of elements or are you accessing that element by className for lack of another way to bind it?

Comment: because either way, the statement click1.addEventListener(... should be click1[0].addEventListener to get the 1st element in the click1 collection

Comment: other than that, the code looks like it will work. you may want to wrap it up in a DOM loaded event like I did in my code

Answer (score 0):

ok, refactored code for no changes to html:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
var click1 = document.getElementsByClassName('buffalo');
var click2 = document.getElementsByClassName('tiger');
var hide1 = ['widget2', 'widget4', 'widget6', 'widget8', 'widget10', 'widget12'];
var hide2 = ['widget1', 'widget3', 'widget5', 'widget7', 'widget9', 'widget11'];  

[].forEach.call(click1, element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
        for(i = 0; i < hide1.length; i++){
            if (document.getElementById(hide2[i]).style.display == "block") {
                document.getElementById(hide2[i]).style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById(hide1[i]).style.display = "block";
            }
        } 
    });
});

[].forEach.call(click2, element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
        for(i = 0; i < hide2.length; i++){
            if (document.getElementById(hide1[i]).style.display == "block") {
                document.getElementById(hide1[i]).style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById(hide2[i]).style.display = "block";
            } 
        } 
    });
});
```

});